# Preventing NavLink behaviour for another element inside the NavLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm not even sure if this is a good questions. Apologies if I don't make any sense.

I have the following structure for an NavLink:

```
<NavLink to="/path">
<div onClick={()=>{...function}} ></div>
</NavLink>
```

How can I prevent the div to direct the user to the path if they click on the div inside the NavLink? I have used e.preventDefault() and it worked for but not completely. The div has inputs too, would onChange trigger the NavLink behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there. It is generally a bad practice to have `input`s inside a Navlink. What is your exact use case.

Comment: Why do you need this content to be wrapped in a NavLink?

Comment: It is difficult to explain, but I have an item that holds different features, a div with a few other functionalities (rating, drop menu for that item. Then, if a users clicks in the full item it direct them to a different page that provides a close up of the item they were looking in the previous page (smaller version with less data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in the `div` click handler, the event won't bubble up to the link.

Demo with native JavaScript, will work with React as well:

```js
const [a, div] = ['a', 'div'].map(document.getElementById.bind(document));

div.addEventListener('click', e => e.stopPropagation());

a.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('doh')); // never happens
```

```css
#div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a id="a">
  <div id="div"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: thank you. This just made the trick! :) thank you !